# ESP32 serial stream freezing

Tags: arduino, serial-port, freeze

I have a master device and ESP32 acting as a slave, communicating directly over UART with RX/TX cables. I've created a task that checks the serial stream every 50 ms and parses the data. My problem is that the serial stream freezes up, seemingly randomly, and only restarts if the master or the slave are restarted.

The task looks as such:

```cpp
void TaskListen_UART(void *pvParameters)
{
  while (true)
  {
    if (readSerialIn()) 
    {
      slaveRunCommand(serialData.command); // Execute received commmand
    }
    vTaskDelay(50 / portTICK_PERIOD_MS);
  }
}
```

It checks the serial stream through `readSerialIn()` which looks like the following:

```cpp
bool readSerialIn()
{
    if (UART.available() > 0) // Check if the Serial port received data
    {
        serialData.clearStruct(); // Clear previously saved data
        if (UART.find(0x2A)) // Find "*" // Find starting delimiter 
        {
            serialData.length = UART.read(); // Read length
            if (serialData.length > BYTE_BUFFER_LEN)
            {
                writeSerialNACK(); // Write NACK if length seems incorrect 
                return false;
            }
            Serial.printf(("Message length: %d\n"), serialData.length);
            serialData.checksum = UART.read(); // Read Checksum
            Serial.printf(("Checksum:  %d\n"), serialData.checksum);
            if (parseBuffer(serialData.length)) // Parse the data
            {
                if (serialData.checkSum()) // If the checksum passes
                {
                    serialData.assignBuffer(); // Save the parsed data to the global buffer
                    return true;
                }
                else
                {
                    writeSerialNACK();
                    return false;
                }
            }
            else
                false;
        }
        else
            return false;
    }
}
```

The `parseBuffer()` function is what actually reads the stream and parses it into their according values on the slave. I tried to write it in the most fail-safe fashion, but it still hasn't cleared up my issue.

```cpp
bool parseBuffer(uint8_t bufferLength)
{
    uint8_t bufferPos = 0;
    bool uartDetectFlag = false;
    while (UART.available() > 0)
    {
        uartDetectFlag = true;
        if (bufferPos < bufferLength)
        {
            serialData.serialBuffer[bufferPos] = UART.read();
        }
        bufferPos++;
    }
    if (uartDetectFlag)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

At first I was suspicious that the ESP was trying to access a block in memory that doesn't exist. I noticed however that it doesn't reset itself like it normally would if that were the case, and I tried writing `parseBuffer` in a non-blocking manner. I also tried increasing the task delay to 100 ms, which reduced the frequency of the blocking but did not suffice in terms of speed. Regardless, it freezes up and (I think) it's caused by a large flow of data through the serial stream.

Comment: You're not clear at all as to where this "*task*" is executing, on either the "*master*" or the ESP32.  What is the messaging protocol?  Which direction seems to have issue?  You probably have too many unknowns, and need to simplify the problem.  *"I've created a task that checks the serial stream every 50 ms*" -- Scheduling a task to poll for input is typically a bad idea, since blocking syscalls and event-driven code is more efficient.

Comment: The task is on the ESP32. The protocol is a proprietary so I can't talk about it too much. I'm unsure about that as well, it seems like the ESP32 is freezing up since I can still read the TX output from the master through another device. I had a feeling that it had something to do with the task scheduling, I'm just unsure how to run it in a better fashion.